# OSX Xamarin, System.Drawing namespace not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I am using **Visual Studio for Mac** and trying to revive a project that written in XamarinStudio about 2 years ago.
Code written in C#.

When I try to build the project, there is a lot of error that saying:

```
namespace Drawing does not exist in the namespace System(are you missing an assembly reference?).
```

Past in the time this code compiled.

What package should I install to get System.Drawing namespace or what can substitute System.Drawing namespace?

I need PointF structure from that namespace.

Comment: What type of project is it? `MonoMac`, `Xamarin.Mac`, Mono cmd-line, Mono GTK ....???

Comment: It's a Xamarin.Mac project. 

If I open a Xamarin.IOS project I can use System.Drawing namespace

Comment: I think you didn't read my question properly.

Comment: There is already an using System.Drawing statement.

Comment: What framework is that project using? One of the old "Unsupported" ones, "Full" or "Modern"?

Comment: I did solve this issue, with my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.
The problem solved this way:

I had to migrate my project to **Xamarion.IOS Unified API**.

This option is in Project settings.

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to solve your issue by going to  Project>AddReference and check System.Drawing.

edit : reading your question again, I noticed your using VS for Mac, I don't know if you have such options then.